# How can I download and install saslauthd?

Tags: 11.04, server, package-management, sasl

I cannot find saslauthd on my Ubuntu 11.04, and I did not find any package to install it.
How to install, which package contains it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are probably looking for `sasl2-bin`. You can install it via synaptic or by using the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install sasl2-bin
```